# calculating a vector between three vectors or more

Tags: c++, vector, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization, calculus

am trying to get a vector of dimension >200 between two vectors by   calculating,

```
        resVector = k*v1 + (1-k)*v2
```

save the new resultant vector and delete

```
    v1, v2
```

is there any way that i can add another third vector , so i can later delete all

```
    v1, v2, v3
```

and have the new resultant vector,
i have done that in series but it would be good if i can do that faster.

Thanks!

Comment: How is this relevant to tags `c++`, `mathematical-optimization` and `calculus`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your are looking for a **weighting vector** computation.

Thus a good way to do that in general manner is:

1. Compute the ratio vector
2. Apply in parallel that ratio to each vector
3. Apply a reduction (+:resVector)

Search for omp reduction.